# Clockwork Goliath. Trying to make it work

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, skills

So I have this idea to make a 5e Goliath that's missing an arm and a leg but keeps fighting, made clockwork body parts to replace the ones that he lost. He has to wind himself at least once a day. If he fails to do so then he Can't really move. getting disadvantages on almost everything physical. How easy would it be to make it. I know its kind of a homebrew, but it's feasible to build as goliaths are still required to pull their own weight in the clan regardless of physical condition or age, otherwise they are cast out.

I'm using the Goliath build from the Elemental Evil D&D Companion. They are high risk taking characters, hence the missing limbs, they are EXTREMELY self reliant, hence the building of his own extra limbs. A normal prosthesis like a peg leg, wouldn't help them carry their weight like a moving usable prosthesis would. I'm just trying to figure out what the skills would need to be, and what feats this goliath would reasonable not be able to have due to his ailment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like your Goliath needs a close association with a Rock Gnome.  Maybe it's a friendship.  Maybe the Goliath saved the Gnome's life and the Gnome now serves him out of gratitude, or maybe the Goliath enslaved the Gnome, or sold himself to the Gnome's service in return for the rebuilding, or whatever.  Maybe the Gnome is an NPC, or maybe another PC.

But whatever the story, the Gnome built the limbs for the Goliath, which count as two of the three gadgets the Gnome may have running at any given time, and they both have to spend a couple hours a day with the Gnome maintaining the limbs.

Perhaps to balance that, the pair have an extra advantage or two for working together.  Maybe they have had a special saddle made, that sits on the Goliath's shoulders, and the Gnome rides him, and they sometimes charge together with the Gnome carrying a lance, and when they do that, there's a roll to knock an opponent prone.

This is just one of a million possible suggestions.  It's your story -- go wild with it.